# Android unit test for camera preview?

Tags: android, unit-testing, opencv, camera, mocking

i try to unit test my camera preview image, is it possible to set a static image as "camera image" during testing or should i try implementing my own mock object?

I'm looking for something like:

```
myCameraMock.setImage(image);
myCameraDispatcher.setCamera(myCameraMock);
```

(I'm working with the opencv camera)

thanks

Comment: are you using espresso?

Answer (score 0):

In general I would create a wrapper/adapter that only exposes the needed functionality of such an external dependency. Apart from being able to easer adapt to changes of the external dependency, you can also mock the adapter in your tests and let it do things you could not do so easily with the dependecy itself. For your example, you could it have return a predefined image in your test and it is also easier to test if your code behaves properly in presence of failures (that are usually hard to trigger with the real thing.